# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values ' ', '*'

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working with ASP.NET WEB Api, and I'm using authentication Token, Internet Explorer generates the Token string:

[image]

But using any other browser shows the following error :

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

[image]

AJAX code:

```
function ObtenerToken(user, password) {

            var data = { username: user, password: password, grant_type: "password" }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:50196/Token',
                method: "post",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json",
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Hubo un error al intentar autenticar al usuario.');
                    console.log(e);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var token = response.access_token;
                    alert(token);

                }
            });
        }
```

The file Startup.Auth.cs i have set the following

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

In WebApiConfig.cs

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```

And in class Controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class UsuariosController : ApiController
    {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because you're adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in all three of those places. You should enable CORS in Startup.Auth.cs, in WebApiConfig.cs, OR in the controller - one of these places, not all three.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable cors.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        // Make sure this line is called before ConfigureAuth(app), 
        // app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```